# Otimização no carregamento de imagens SVG

Tags: html5, imagem, svg

Estou criando um site que contém diversas imagens em SVG. Já tentei criar um sprite com algumas imagens e embutir direto no CSS (background-image).

Após pesquisar por diversos dias não consegui achar nenhuma solução para melhorar o carregamento das imagens que funcione em todos os navegadores (IE10+) e que não precise baixar dezenas de arquivos.

Como poderia otimizar o carregamento de imagens em SVG?

Comment: Nope, é um SPA, todas as imagens devem ser carregadas quando a página é acessada. Além disso diversas imagens já são exibidas na tela inicial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas técnicas, mas a base é eliminar códigos desnecessários de dentro dos SVG e fazer a minificação do arquivo final.

***Essa opção é para tratar o arquivo .svg antes dele ser requerido ok. Ele não trata a requisição do servidor, mas sim o tamanho do arquivo que será baixado do servidor.***

Existem serviços on-line como o SVGOMG que te ajudam a limpar o SVG. Vc consegue redução de cerca de 60% no tamanho final dos arquivos. https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

Exemplo de uso. Repare na lista de atributos que vc pode alterar e remover a direita.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o projeto deles no Git: https://github.com/jakearchibald/svgomg/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Já estou otimizando todos os SVGs utilizando um programa desktop (SVG Cleaner => https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner-gui).

Comment: Já utilizei este site antes e acho muito útil.

Comment: @Pilati se vc já está otimizando os arquivos agora não tem mais muito o que fazer no .svg propriamente dito. A melhor forma que vc poderia fazer seria injetar o código dele dentro do documento na hora de subir para o cliente. Assim vc deixa os arquivos separados apenas no ambiente de desenvolvimento, mas quando subir pro server vc coloca o código do svg direto na página, isso te pouparia muitas requisições pelo visto.

Comment: Sim, porém não seria possível de cachear, gostaria de uma solução em que, pelo menos, eu pudesse colocar o código do SVG no CSS ou JS, pois são arquivos que são usados apenas uma vez. tentei colocar no `bacground-image: url('Codigo svg')` porém teria que definir o tamanho de cada imagem na mão, isso complicaria na responsividade do site, pois uma imagem de background não ajusta o tamanho da div como uma imagem normal

Comment: Não achei nenhuma forma em que eu pudesse realmente "substituir" o conteúdo da imagem via CSS usando o url

Comment: @Pilati Não ficaria no cache mesmo não... No momento não consigo pensar em outra solução... :(, mas se eu lembrar de algo eu comento aqui

Comment: E pra essa pergunta eu to aceitando qualquer tipo de resposta que ajudaria a diminuir o tempo de "fetch" da página. Pesquisei muito sobre o HTTP/2, porém o meu servidor ainda não tem suporte. Pesquisei sobre usar o CacheManifest, porém não consegui testar com sucesso